# how to validate the hostel code model field with api in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
def ran_gen(size, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

class StudentRoom(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    property_room_id = models.ForeignKey(PropertyRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    student_hostel_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=ran_gen(6), editable=False)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    allocated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student_hostel_code)
```

Comment: I suggest you read the Django documenation about validators.

Comment: Please put more elaborative text